# I can't find the right pathname

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm sorry for such an easy question.

In my articles.js file I want to include the find.js file. I just can't get the pathname right and I feel I have tried every possibility and I can't find the solution online. Could someone please help me?

Here is a picture of  [my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VxHR.png)

**articles.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const _ = require('lodash');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const find = require("./config/functions/find.js")               //This one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do local imports, you need to use the **relative** path. In your case, `articles.js` is inside of `routes`, so you should go one level up (`..`), and then navigate through config -> functions (`/config/functions`):

```js
const find = require('../config/functions/find')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason I was not able to learn this by myself, thank you for helping me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up a directory, like this:

```
const find = require("../config/functions/find.js");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a little thing took me so long. Have a nice day